# Toolbar on JFrame wont update, Singleton

Tags: java, swing

I have JFrame called MainWindow

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private static MainWindow instance = null;

    public static MainWindow getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MainWindow();
            instance.init();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

In init() method I got menuPopulate() and toolbarPopulate() methods where I'm adding menu items and toolbar items. My MainWindow is singleton, also I have menuItem called "NewKeyPairPL" and it is setVisible(false) on the beginning. **Here I'm trying to enable menu item from my controller**

My problem is when I want to set to set NewKeyPairPL menu item to be setVisible(true). I am doing that from controller and its not updating. Here is my code to do it:

```
MainWindow.getInstance().getNewKeyPairPL().setVisible(true);
MainWindow.getInstance().getNewKeyPairPL().repaint();
MainWindow.getInstance().getNewKeyPairPL().revalidate();

MainWindow.getInstance().getToolBar().repaint();
MainWindow.getInstance().getToolBar().revalidate();

MainWindow.getInstance().repaint();
MainWindow.getInstance().revalidate();
```

Also, if I try same thing from MainWindow class like this:

```
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        newKeyPairPL.setEnabled(true);
    }

});
```

(btn1 is one of the buttons in my toolbar)

it is working, but thats not what I need.

Comment: What is newKeyPairPL ?

Comment: I wrote, its menu item which i want to set to be visible because its not visible on the beginning.

Comment: Maybe you can try reducing this down to an example where you have just a JFrame and a JMenu. From your "answer" it sounds like you are making more than one "MainWindow". Perhaps you should synchronize the method.

Comment: Please add a complete, compilable code sample.